# Issue with Variable Update in PrimeFaces Component

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, commandlink

I have a `commandLink` that is loaded with information inside a dataTable, the logic is that when the variable `showPopup` is `true` it shows me a popup, otherwise it does not show it. The variable changes depending on certain conditions and it is managed in my bean in a method that is called popup. The problem that I have is that when this `commandLink` is clicked it is not taking the value of the variable `showPopup` that the method assigns it, but if it is changing the value of the variable for what if I want that it works I must give it another click and there it takes the wished value. In summary I believe that the commandLink does not update the value of the variable showPopup when this changes in the method.
The bean is `@ManagedBean @RequestScoped`

```html
<!-- more code -->

<t:fieldset styleClass="fieldsetEstilo"
            legend="#{mensaje.label_roles}">
  <h:panelGroup id="roles">
    <p:outputPanel id="outputRoles">
      <p:message for="tRoles" />
      <p:dataTable value="#{usuario.listaRoles}" var="objRol"
                   id="tRoles" reflow="true"
                   emptyMessage="#{mensaje.message_no_existen_registros}">
        <f:facet name="header">#{mensaje.label_listado_de} #{mensaje.rol_label_s}</f:facet>
        <p:column styleClass="W16P">
          <f:facet name="header" />


          <!-- HERE IS MY COMMAND LINK -->

          <p:commandLink id="asignarLink" styleClass="estiloIcono"
                         actionListener="#{usuarioAction.setRolPJ(objRol)}"
                         action="#{usuarioAction.limpiarFechasRoles()}"
                         oncomplete="if ('#{usuarioAction.mostrarPopupAsignarRol}' == 'true') { PF('popUpAsignarRol').show(); };"
                         update=":usuarioForm:outputRoles, :usuarioForm:tablaRolesUsuario, :asignarRol, asignarLink"
                         process="@this">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" />
            <p:tooltip for="asignarLink" position="top">
              <p:outputLabel value="#{mensaje.label_asignar}" />
            </p:tooltip>
          </p:commandLink>

          <!-- more code -->
```

I have tried to change some values of the action and update properties of the `commandLink` but I have not achieved any change.

Comment: Please read [tag:jsf] (learn more...) and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: I only change the visible property in the p:dialog, my problem was in the property oncomplete of the p:commandLink